# AjaxControlToolkit button not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

why button of text editor for AjaxControlToolkit not working with me like 
color font - size only drop down worked ok 
but others one can't uses

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

```
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />



                                    <label class="control-label">Enter Title News</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Title1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                    <label class="control-label"> Content News</label>
                                    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Hello, there. Can you explain what are you trying to acheive

Comment: i use ajaxtoolkit and i want use the button in this editor an example change color of font or change the background ? all the buttons not worked when click on ...

Comment: Here's a website demosntrating how to get started with it: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs

Comment: I'm still having some trouble understanding what is it about buttons. Where is the button? It's not in your code

Comment: i mean this https://s32.postimg.org/kngf7ezv9/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

You must use TargetControlID like that

```
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" TargetControlID="Title1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: full example for use target control ? plz

Comment: this is an example [Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-HtmlEditorExtender-Example.aspx) .

Comment: you are welcome, Please make this answer is correct and useful, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem.

Open this link: [HTML Editor Sample](http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx)
You say you try to change the font-color and background pressing the control buttons. Those buttons work when you select the text first.

Type something into the Editor, then select that text.
After that press the font-color change button. It should turn you text into another color.

It works the same way with the background.

Also, if you press the button, then star typing, your text should start showing the color. (Works exactly like Word)

Answer (score 0):

problem was when page load the editor tool and when i want post content

if when i press on button there is not working like (fore color , insert link )

This problem was due to my use bootstrap because when i create new web form and include the editor it's working fine and all the buttons can press and uses

Thank you for helping me